# Why does my if not pass in the else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I do an if to do an ajax query. If my string 'page' is undefined or does not contain the word 'page =', I want to execute my ajax query.

I specify that the variable page (which is a "href"), changes every time the ajax query is generated.

`var page = $(this).attr('href');`

If not, I want to go into my 'else'.

Can you tell me what is wrong? I'm lost.

```
if (typeof page !== 'undefined' || page.search('page=') !== -1 ){
                $.ajax({
                    url: page,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        button.addClass('loading');
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.former-students__list').append(data.students);
                        button.attr('href', data.next_page);
                        button.removeClass('loading');
                        w.ajaxGraduated.initGrid();
                    },
                })
            } else {
                button.addClass('finish');
                button.attr(href, '');
                $('.load-more__label-text').text('Vous avez tout vu !');
            }
```

Comment: Your description of the condition and the condition itself are opposite. Right now if it *is* `undefined`, it'll throw an error because it goes to the RHS of the `||`. You should structure the condition as you described it... `if (page === undefined || page.search('page=') === -1) {...`

Comment: ...notice that I didn't use `typeof` to check `undefined`. There's just no need for that. It causes worse problems than those it supposedly fixes.

Comment: ...though weirdly you say that if `page` is `undefined`, you *want* to execute the query. But if it's `undefined`, you don't have a valid `url`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it should be an AND condition and not an OR:

```
if ((typeof page !== 'undefined') && (page.search('page=') !== -1 )) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the if block to run when

> 'page' is undefined or does not contain the word 'page ='

then you should use "===" for the first condition and not "!==".

```
if (typeof page === 'undefined' || page.search('page=') !== -1 ){
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using normal operator == or != inside if statement?

```
if (typeof page != 'undefined' || page.search('page=') != -1 ){
```

and, as Eldad commented, I think you should use an AND as if the typeof is not undefined it will enter the if in any case, no matter the page.search.